# shiny: Is there a way to create new conditionalPanels based on click button?

Tags: user-interface, shiny, module

I have a shiny app with a click button and a selectInput widget which allows a user to select a specific country.
Each time I click on the button I want to add a new selectInput which I do with a conditionalPanel.
I am using module functions for the selectInputs because I also want to update the choices of each selectInput so that the user can never select the same country twice. So whenever the user chooses a country in a selectInput all other selectInput choices are updated to exclude this selected country.

Is there a way to create a new conditionalPanel line of code whenever the button is clicked? Instead of having lots of conditionalPanels in the code?
Is there a way to automatically create a list of all the countries which have been selected?

Thank you so much for your help!

This is what I have created:

`   library(shiny)

```
country_list <- list(
  "Africa" = c("Ghana", "Burundi", "Ethiopia"),
  "Europe" = c("Germany", "Belgium", "Luxembourg") 
)

moduleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  wellPanel(
    h4(paste0("This is module id"), id),
    selectInput(ns("select"), label="Make a choice: ", choices=c("", country_list),    
    selected=NULL)
  )
}

moduleController <- function(input, output, session, choices, selected_choice) {
  ns <- session$ns

  observeEvent(req(nchar(choices())>1), {
    updateSelectInput(session, "select", choices = c(map(country_list, ~.[!(. %in%  
choices())])), selected=selected_choice())
  })

  returnValue <- reactive({
    input$select
  })
  return(returnValue)
}

ui <- fixedPage(

  actionButton("addLine", "Add Line"),
  selectInput("country1Mode", label="Select first country", choices=country_list, 
  selected=NULL),

  #moduleUI("Country1"),
  #moduleUI("Country2"),

  conditionalPanel("input.addLine >= 1",
                   moduleUI("Country1")),

  conditionalPanel("input.addLine >= 2",
                   moduleUI("Country2")),

  conditionalPanel("input.addLine >= 3",
                   moduleUI("Country3")),

  textOutput("country1Text"),
  textOutput("country2Text"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  countries_selected <- reactive({
    c(input$country1Mode, country2(), country3())
  })

  countries_selected2 <- reactive({
    c(input$country1Mode, country1(), country3())
  })

  countries_selected3 <- reactive({
    c(input$country1Mode, country1(), country2())
  })

  country1 <- callModule(moduleController, "Country1", reactive({countries_selected()}),    
                         reactive({country1()}))
  country2 <- callModule(moduleController, "Country2", reactive({countries_selected2()}), 
              reactive({country2()}))
  country3 <- callModule(moduleController, "Country3", reactive({countries_selected3()}), 
              reactive({country3()}))

  observe({
    if (is(country1(), "character")) print(country1())
  })
  observe({
    if (is(country2(), "character")) print(country2())
  })

  output$country1Text <- renderText({
    paste("Module 1 selection is", country1(), country2())
  })

  output$country2Text <- renderText({
    paste(countries_selected())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)`
```

This works relatively well but I want to create an automatic way of adding conditionalPanels and an automatic way of extracting the country names which have been selected.

Comment: In particular, check out the "Adding/removing UI with insertUI and removeUI" section : https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html

Comment: @Marcus Thanks for your comment. Yes, that is how I originally approached the problem but unfortunately insertUI is not reactive, and I need to change the UI after I have inserted it.

Comment: Typically you call it from inside `observe` or `observeEvent` which can add reactivity

Comment: Unfortunately, insertUI is not reactive, even in observeEvent.